# Как объяснить расстановку знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Наткнулся на закрытый модератором вопрос.

**Весь золотой кофейный лиловый по краям аккордеон трофейный попал однажды к нам. Помогите расставить знаки препинания в предложении.**

Это какое-то стихотворение, как я понял, а значит - интересный слог.

В школе человеку задали задание - расставить знаки препинания.

Как это бывает в наших школах, есть лишь один верный вариант ответа.

Но мне интересно! Если перед словом "аккордеон" поставить многоточие, то будет ли это ошибкой?

Возможно ли поставить перед этим же словом авторское тире?

Если всё это возможно, то как школьнику дать единственно верный ответ в задании?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что от школьников требовалось расставить запятые - "Весь золотой, кофейный, лиловый по краям, аккордеон трофейный попал однажды к нам."

Comment: Это понятно.Но вопрос не в этом.

Comment: Я бы так объяснила школьникам: Предложение состоит из двух частей, одна из которых - описательная - "Весь золотой, кофейный, лиловый по краям", и вторая - повествовательная - "Аккордеон трофейный попал однажды к нам". Поэтому разделяем эти две части запятыми.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуем переделать предложение: "Золотой, кофейный, лиловый по краям трофейный аккордеон  однажды попал к нам в полк". Здесь  постановка запятой не является обязательной, актуализация однородного ряда - дело автора.

В приведенном примере обязательное обособление задает инверсия неоднородного определения "трофейный": "Весь золотой, кофейный, лиловый по краям, аккордеон трофейный попал однажды к нам". Но более сильного знака, чем запятая, не требуется.

В то же время объяснить причину обособления для школьников достаточно сложно.